# Handling Multiline Cells in Ruby CSV

Tags: ruby, csv, newline

```
require 'csv'
input = CSV.read("test_first.csv", :encoding => 'ascii')[1 .. -1]
DOC = "test_final.csv"

profile = []

profile[0] = "Multiline"
profile[1] = "Standard"

CSV.open(DOC, mode = 'w', :force_quotes => true) do |me|
 me << profile
end


a = 0 
b = input.length 
while a < b 
 temp = []
 temp = input[a]
 profile = []

 profile[0] = ' A text string with embedded newlines
 as well as some substitution from the source file: '"#{temp[0]}"''
 profile[1] = temp[1]

 CSV.open(DOC, mode = "a", :force_quotes => true ) do |me|
    me << profile
  end
  a += 1
end
```

The resulting file test_final.csv retains the desired newlines within the cells however the force_quotes isn't working as expected and the embedded newlines aren't being escaped. So when the test_final.csv is reviewed in a text editor it has more lines than intended because each newline is being treated as a new row.

I tried appending the offending column with it's own unique row separator> profile[0] = ' A text string with embedded newlines
     as well as some substitution from the source file: '"#{temp[0]}"'~' and assigning that in the options hash like so> :row_sep => "~" but this didn't seem to work.

Some clarification as to the desired input and output

```
Desired Input:
test_first.csv
1.testHeader1,testheader2
2.sub1,standard1
3.sub2,standard2

Desired Output:
test_final.csv
1.Multiline,Standard
2. A text string with embedded newlines
     as well as some substitution from the source file: sub1,standard1
3. A text string with embedded newlines
     as well as some substitution from the source file: sub2,standard2

What I'm getting right now instead is:
test_fail.csv
1.Multiline,Standard
2. A text string with embedded newlines
3.    as well as some substitution from the source file: sub1,standard1
4. A text string with embedded newlines
5.    as well as some substitution from the source file: sub2,standard2
```

Comment: can you give us some sample and some expected output?

Comment: I tried to do so at the top but I'm not sure how to format csv here on SO. I will edit the question to help clarify.